# How to overwrite settings for a folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a folder inside a workspace and I need to overwrite some settings only for that folder. How to do that ? (probably a stupid question but I've been trying for last half hour with no success)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `.vscode/settings.json` file inside that folder. These settings will overwrite your workspace settings for this folder only - cf [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_settings).

Comment: I've made a quick test and it doesn't work unless you define a multi-root workspace and explicitly add each subfolder to the project (it doesn't check or care if multi-root project folders are nested).